# Why does ReflectionClass::getMethods() returns private methods from parent class?

Tags: php, reflection

Consider the following snippet:

```php
class A {
    private function foo() {}
    protected function bar() {}
}
class B extends A {
    private function baz() {}
}

$r = new ReflectionClass('B');
foreach ($r->getMethods() as $method) {
    echo $method->getName() . PHP_EOL;
}
```

I would expect the following output:

```
baz
bar
```

But the actual output is:

```
baz
foo
bar
```

Why does [getMethods()](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) return private methods from parent classes, and therefore out of the scope of the class being reflected, `B`?

I'm wondering if there is any rationale behind this, or if this is a bug that should be filed?

Answer (score -1):

No, it's not a bug. This function does exactly what it designed for. Also, check out the link you gave in your question, there is a `filter` parameter, which can be used to set attributes of methods to return.

Comment: I've seen the `filter` parameter, but not filter seems to be designed for what I expect the method to return. Can you explain the rationale behind your reasoning? `foo()` is not in the scope of `B`.

Comment: Also, I just did the same test with `ReflectionClass::getProperties()`, and this one works as I expect it to: it returns `baz` and `bar`, but not `foo`.

Comment: @Benjamin Oh, I see. Sorry, I didn't properly understand question first time.

Comment: @Benjamin Maybe you could achieve the behaviour by iterating over getMethods() result and checking `::getModifiers()` and `::getDeclaringClass()`?

Comment: Yes I can definitely exclude the methods which are private and whose getDeclaringClass() returns a different class name. But if this is a PHP bug, it still needs to be fixed :)

Comment: I got your point. I agree that they should fix `::getMethods()` or `::getProperties()` to behave the same. And I think that the `::getMethods()` behaviour is right.

Comment: I actually think the opposite: every ReflectionClass should return methods and properties that are in its scope. If you want the private methods/properties in the scope of the parent class, you use another ReflectionClass on this class. Can you explain what's *your* reasoning?

Comment: My reasoning is that you must be able to get _all_ the methods and properties defined in class tree. But it would be useful to have the flag in this functions to return only methods and properties visible to current class.

Comment: But then, if you have a `private foo()` method in class A, and a `public foo()` method in class B, these will be two different functions. Would you expect to have `foo` returned twice then, once for A and once for B?

Comment: No, I expect to return the overriden one. My point is getMethods() should return all method contained by instance, sorry for mention class tree :)